# retrieve files from sharepoint library failed after few files

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml

Below is my code, it worked with too files and when ExecuteQuery load the third one, an error is **timeout**. no other error message got
.

```
ListItemCollection  items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
    spoContext.Load(items);

                spoContext.ExecuteQuery();
                if (items.Count > 0)
                {

                    foreach (ListItem item in items)
                    {
                    try
                    {
                         File = item.File;
                        spoContext.Load(File);
                        spoContext.ExecuteQuery();   // error after load 2 files,the third one can not be load


                        var filedata = File;
                        String filePath = filedata.ServerRelativeUrl;
                        String fileName = filedata.Name;

                        FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(spoContext, filePath);
                        Stream stream = fileInfo.Stream;


                        if (stream != null)
                        {
                            using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                            {
                                uploadFile(spoDestContext, ListName, fileName, mStream, "", 2);
                                mStream.Close();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        File = null;
                    }
                   }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

it shows that this is a timeout exception. You could have a try to increase the timeout of the clientcontext that you generated.

```
using(ClientContext context=new ClinetContext("http://aboc.come/sites/test"))
{
   context..RequestTimeout= 20 * 60 * 1000;
}
```

more reference: [ClientRuntimeContext.RequestTimeout property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541007(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)